# GIN and GIST indexing in Postgres for k-d trees? (NOT full-text searches or geographic coordinates)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, kdtree

I've been looking for information on using GIN and GIST indexes, for implementing [*k*-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), but every time I've looked, inevitably every result is about geographic coordinates (and thus assumes you're using PostGIS) or full-text searching, which bears little resemblance to the type of indexing I'm trying to do.

What I'd really like to do is to use a *k*-d tree algorithm to search a database of about 500,000 similar items in *k* dimensions (where *k* ~ 8-12 and can vary based on category), using a custom N-nearest-neighbors algorithm that's been optimized to use only integer values as input.  But obviously, that's much too specific to find anything at all, and loosening my search terms gets me a bunch of full-text-search tutorials.  Can someone please at least point me in the right direction?  There's almost nothing in the official Postgres documentation, and what information is there has been shown to be inaccurate and/or outdated in a lot of the more recent information I've been able to find.

Really, any information regarding how one might implement a *k*-d tree type of indexing algorithm in Postgres would be immensely helpful to me.

Comment: You might be suffering from a terminology problem. It's outside my area of expertise but does https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=postgresql+knn+index return what you were looking for?

Comment: Is the [`cube` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html) helpful to you? It defines a datatype and a GiST index for it. It operates on *64-bit floating point numbers* instead of integers, but I think this may be the closest to what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, it allows you to calculate with distances other than euclidean. Which is [typically not a good choice for dimensions higher than 9 anyway](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions).